# Break all lines in CSS if one breaks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've a part of code on my website. Some time it can happen that the line breaks if the code don't fit in the parent element anymore:

[image]

If this happens I want to break all lines instead because it looks ugly when one part is broken and the other don't.

**Remind**
I can have a least 20 elements in one list.

**Update**
This is the part of my code which I all need to wrap if one of them wraps:

```css
.elements-list {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  list-style: none outside;
}

.list-entry {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  list-style: none outside;
  padding-right: 8px;
  max-width: 200px;
}

span.single-detail span {
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    display: -webkit-inline-box;
    display: inline-flex;
    display: -ms-inline-flexbox;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<ul class="elements-list">
  <li class="list-entry">
    <span class="single-detail">
      <span>Abgabefrist:</span>
      <span>22.02.2222</span>
    </span>
    <span class="single-detail">
      <span>Entlohnung:</span>
      <span>2.222,00 €</span>
    </span>
  </li>
  <li class="list-entry">
    <span class="single-detail">
      <span>Abgabefrist:</span>
      <span>22.02.2222</span>
    </span>
    <span class="single-detail">
      <span>Entlohnung:</span>
      <span>20.222,00 €</span>
    </span>
  </li>
  <li class="list-entry">
    <span class="single-detail">
      <span>Abgabefrist:</span>
      <span>22.02.2222</span>
    </span>
    <span class="single-detail">
      <span>Entlohnung:</span>
      <span>22.000.222,00 €</span>
    </span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Think you would need js for this - css won't tell you if the text is wrapping

Comment: Hm thats right. So I may need to find out in JS if the element wrapped up. If yes, I need to add a class for example wrapped to all elements which forces everything to wrap. What do you think about this?

Comment: Unless you are using a server side language to populate this - you could check the length of the euros if any are over a certain length that causes the wrap, then add a class to the container (if you don't want to do this with js)

Comment: Thats a good idea! But when I have the website fully opened, I want to show everything inline but when you minimize the window, I need to wrap when one wraps. So add a class if euro bigger x is not a final solution. Maybe I can check in js on window resize if the text wraps? Or is this to slow?

Comment: Alternatively, just line break every time. Benefits: consistency, having this issue done and working on something else.

Comment: @WesleyMurch Also thought of this but this will make look everything very wired on a big desktop

Comment: Hmmm, yeah sounds like js solution would be best for you then - would need to check on load and resize.  I would probably give each line a container with a line height (bigger than the font) then you can check to see if the container's height is larger than the line height - something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/5btjoke1/10/

Comment: It's not clear what you want to wrap.  Should the text of each span inside single-detail be kept together or can the euro symbol be on a different line to the value that precedes it?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can solve this with CSS alone. You can solve it with JavaScript.

One way would be to constantly monitor the elements and see if one of them wrapped. But then, once wrapped you will never unwrap, it's not responsive.

So this is my alternative: 
By putting the value inside `inline-block` elements, you can align the widths of the elements. This way, when one element wraps, they will all wrap, because they simply won't fit anymore.

Advantages of this solution:

- It's responsive, responds to browser resizing.
- Only requires JavaScript on load. Sizing and wrapping is handled by CSS once the widths are set, so it's fairly lightweight.

Disadvantages:

- You will need to recalculate the widths if you change the content of the elements, or if you have dynamic font sizing (I hope not).
- It's not pixel perfect, it seems. Maybe it can be tuned (for instance by giving the left element also a width in whole pixels), or otherwise, maybe you'll forgive me this pixel. ;)

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
  var rows = document.querySelectorAll('.row');
  // First loop to find which line is the widest.
  var widest = 0;
  for(r=0; r<rows.length; r++) {
    console.log(r);
    var width = rows[r].querySelector('.col1').offsetWidth + 
                rows[r].querySelector('.col2').offsetWidth;
                
    if (width > widest) widest = width;
  }
  // second loop to set the width of col2, so they all
  // get the same width.
  for(r=0; r<rows.length; r++) {
    rows[r].querySelector('.col2').style.width = 
      (widest - rows[r].querySelector('.col1').offsetWidth) + 'px';
  }
});
```

```css
/* This is needed */
.col2 {
  display: inline-block;
}

/* This is just for show */
.col1 {
  padding-right: 1em;
}

span {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<!-- hacky div/span table, since there is no HTML in the question -->
<div class="row"><span class="col1">The time</span><span class="col2">2018-12-22 12:34</span></div>
<div class="row"><span class="col1">Total price here</span><span class="col2">$ 5,-</span></div>
```

Comment: I've tried it but seems to be very strange. It's propperley not working. I've added now something from my code. It's rebuild but the structure and the CSS is the same. When you run it you can see the issue. So if some element wraps, I need to set for example a class wrapped to all of them which wraps them automatically - maybe.

Comment: I see, I think I didn't fully understand the question. I though you only wanted the value after Abgabefrist and Entlohnung to wrap at the same time, but you actually got three columns of those. Then it's a bit harder, because as soon as one of them wraps, the others will fit. I don't know if you always have exact 3 list-entry's, and whether they can wrap as well.. Things like that would make it a lot harder.

Comment: Maybe a better solution then would be to have it slightly less flexible. If not wrapping _always_, as Wesley Murch suggested, at least wrap always if your screen is smaller than some predetermined value. That way, you have have the wide display on wide screens, but anything with a lower resolution will wrap, even if it maybe strictly doesn't need to. If the lengths of your texts will stay within certain boundaries (and since they are numbers, it looks like they will), this could lead to a decent result with not too much effort.

Comment: I've also tried this but the point is that when I make the browser smaller, the layout changes from 4 to 2 columns so in this case it fit's again. And when I work now with @media, the elements are wrapped in the 2 column layout too. So my thoughts are to check if one of the elements wrapped, if yes, add a class to all elements which contains a flex-direction: column. Maybe possible?

Comment: I think that's possible. The only problem is that if you would make the browser wider again, they won't unwrap, unless you keep checking (in some hidden element), if the page is wide enough to display the non-wrapped elements again. Or just ignore that fact, and keep them wrapped if users would resize their browsers like that, that probably wouldn't be a big deal either.

Comment: So all in all it's just a hacky and not a beautiful solution... Any Idea how I can make it better from the layout at the beginning?

Answer (score 0):

You either need to set the css `property white-space: nowrap;` on the text parent element so no text wraps for that class or you could add the `<br>` on the HTML after the name of the element so it breaks every time, code is needed so we can be more specific in finding a solution.

Comment: But in this case the element overflows the parent, or not?

Comment: yes, it would, if no parent has a max-width property or a fixed one, you can also use the property `display: inline` or `display: inline-block;` that way the parent will take the width of it's content

Comment: If I set a max width, my responsive layout will be not longer responsive

Answer (score 0):

Well, easiest would be to create "abgabefrist:01/01/0001" as two elements instead of one and then add display flex to the parent. so when the screen shrinks, the element comes below another.

Below mentioned code fine, tested on codepen.

```css
.dates div {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="dates">
  <div><span>abgabefrist:</span> 
  <span>01/01/0001</span></div>
  <div><span>abgabefrist:</span> 
  <span>02/02/0002</span></div>
    </div>
  <div class="btns">
    <button> Button One</button>
    <button> Button Two </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: They wrap independently, not together. Well, they do wrap together, because in your example both lines are the same length.

Comment: Hey GolezTrol, you are absolutely right. It seems I was in a bit of a hurry when writing that, but the logic remains the same (only differs in layout).